# How to properly add/delete feature to Feature List - mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

i have two methods to DELETE/ADD marker to my APP. When there is a change in database, the marker will be added or removed. Everything was working fine before I add a properties "POPUP" to my feature list.
Now when i have a geopoing and also a POPUP property - removing feature from the feature list is not working. How i can delete feature by passing Geopoint and also the POPUP property.

I need to save in feature Geopoint and String values and when is needed - delete them. Saving is working fine.

```
    private void  delMarkers(double lng, double lat, Style style, String popup_data){
    //THIS LINE BELOW IS NOT WORKING
    symbolLayerIconFeatureList.remove(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lng,lat)));
    /////////////////////
    GeoJsonSource geoJsonSourceSymbol = style.getSourceAs(SOURCE_ID);
    if (geoJsonSourceSymbol != null) {
        geoJsonSourceSymbol.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(symbolLayerIconFeatureList));
    }
}
private void addMarkers(double lng, double lat, Style style, String popup_data){
    feature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lng,lat));
    feature.addStringProperty(POPUP, popup_data);
    symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(feature);

    GeoJsonSource geoJsonSourceSymbol = style.getSourceAs(SOURCE_ID);
    if (geoJsonSourceSymbol != null) {
        geoJsonSourceSymbol.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(symbolLayerIconFeatureList));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the `symbolLayerIconFeatureList.remove(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lng,lat)));` line is causing you issues. You shouldn't do `Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lng,lat))` because this creates a new `Feature`.

It might not be very performant based on how many `Feature`s you have, but you could parse through your `Feature` list, comparing the lat/long of each `Feature` with the lat/long that you've passed through the `delMarkers()` method. Once you've identified which `Feature` should be deleted, pass it through the `remove()` method.

[image]

Comment: I will try comparing lat/long, but i am afraid of performant. The line symbolLayerIconFeatureList.remove(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(lng,lat))); works fine when i do not add POPUP property. I thought that maybe there is a way to remove the feature from the list by parsing both arguments

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea how to make a good foreach loop by coordinates?
I tried like this, but it crashes the app
        for(Feature feature : symbolLayerIconFeatureList){
            if(feature.getStringProperty(POPUP).equals(popup_data)){
                symbolLayerIconFeatureList.remove(feature);
            } else{
                
            }
        }

Comment: Ok, i found a way to do it with iterator, i will use this and check the performance with greater numbers.

        Iterator<Feature> i = symbolLayerIconFeatureList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Feature s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
            if(s.geometry().equals(geometry1)) {
                i.remove();
            }
        }